# SQLBulkCopy connection errors when working with SQL Azure

Tags: sqlbulkcopy, azure-sql-database

We are currently trying out the SQLBulkCopy API on the new SQL Azure CTP.

While we have been able to consistently migrate tables with about a million rows, we are facing connection errors when working with larger tables. We keep getting (after random row transfers) the following error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

I understand that SQL Azure connection policies (mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx)) state that the connection can be terminated for a number of reasons and it also mentions some error codes that are returned.But I am not able to understand which of these might be causing the error or capture the error code.

Is there a way we can get past this error and continue with the migration of table rows?

The SQLBulkCopy options used are:
BatchSize=1000
BulkCopyTimeout = 5000

Answer (score 2):

Knowledge Base article [977291](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977291) gives this error message as a symptom of a Windows 2003 TCP/IP issue.